# setOnItemClickListener don't work when overlapping two listviews

Tags: android, listview

I'm doing an app in which the user can switch between two languages (english and French), I have a fragment in which the data is displayed into a listview, but since the data is different depending on the language selected,  I overlapped two listviews and made one visible depending on the language selected.

Now the issue that I am facing is that the method onItemClicklistener only works for one listview even though the code is almost identical in both cases. I noticed that in the layout the listview that is written last is the one that have the method working. I would like to know if there was a way around this so that both listviews can have their method working.
here's the code , I omitted certains details to keep it short:

```
public class ReportFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
private ListView listView_fr;


public ReportFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report, container,    false);


    reportList = new ArrayList<>();
    reportList_fr = new ArrayList<>();


    listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView_report);
    //Listview for french reports
    listView_fr = view.findViewById(R.id.listView_report_fr);

    if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().contains("en")){
        listView_fr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().contains("fr")){
        listView_fr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view1, position, id) -> {
        Report report = reportList.get(position);

        //Opening the upload file in browser using the upload url
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(report.getUrl()));
        Log.d("TAG", "link en: " + Uri.parse(report.getUrl()));
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    listView_fr.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view12, position, id) ->                  {
        Report_fr report = reportList_fr.get(position);

        //Opening the upload file in browser using the upload url
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(report.getUrl()));
        Log.d("TAG", "link fr: " + Uri.parse(report.getUrl()));
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    return view;
}


}
```

and the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/unicef"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".UI.ReportFragment">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/textview_info_report_fragment"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ListView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView_report_fr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>




        <ListView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView_report"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>



</RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you changing the locale to test which clickListener is working or not??

Comment: Yes that's when I noticed that the clickListener that was working was the one that was from the listview mentioned last in the layout, if I switch the listViews the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the relative layout in the root element of the listview Instead of that use this code

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView_report_fr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight="1"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>




    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView_report"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight="1"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```